# How to calculate the derivate of this function?

Tags: calculus

I have to calculate the derivate of this function:
$$f(x)=\int_0^x g(s,x)ds $$
They don't specify what is $g$ but it's just another function. I think I could use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the chain rule because I've seen some integrals like this one and that's what I have used, but I don't know how to do this with this integral.

Any hint or idea will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use Leibniz rule: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G(s, x)$ be an antiderivative for $g(s, x)$ with respect to $s$. That is $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial s} = g$. Then $f(x) = [G(s, x)]_0^x = G(x, x) - G(0, x)$. Using the chain rule for a function of more than one variable, we have, provided $G$ is $C^2$,

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{\partial G}{\partial s}(x, x)\frac{d}{dx}(x) + \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x, x)\frac{d}{dx}(x) - \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(0, x)\\ 
&= g(x, x) + \left[\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(s, x)\right]_0^x\\
&=g(x, x) + \int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\right)(s, x)ds\\
&= g(x, x) +\int_0^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}\right)(s, x)ds\\
&= g(x, x) + \int_0^x\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(s, x)ds
\end{align*}

which is precisely what you obtain from using the rule in Alex's link.

Comment: How can we be sure that $g$ has an antiderivative?

Comment: In general you can't, but if $g$ is continuous in the first variable it follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @Michael_Albanese shouldn't $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}G(x, x)$ be zero because $G(x,x)$ doesn't depend on $s$?

Comment: Yes $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}G(x, x) = 0$, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}G(x, x)$ is not the same $\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}(x, x)$.

Comment: I thought it was just another notation

Comment: Isn't then $\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}(x, x)=0$ because $G(x,x)$ doesn't depend on $s$? The variables of $G(x,x)$ are only $x$ and $x$, I don't get why you get $s$ when you use the chain rule.

Comment: No, they mean different things. $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}G(x,x)$ means evaluate $G(s, x)$ at $s=x$ and then differentiate with respect to $s$, whereas $\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}(x,x)$ means differentiate with respect to $s$ and then evaluate at $s=x$.

Comment: But $G(x,x)$ is already evaluated at $s=x$, how can you differentiate it with respect to $s$?

Comment: As you said, $G(x, x)$ is constant with respect to $s$ so $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}G(x,x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple deduction:

$\text{Let} f(x)=\int _0^xg(s,x)ds=F(x,g)$

$\text{Then} \frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=g(s,x), \text{with}\text{  }s=x$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\int _0^x \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}ds$

$\text{Thus} \frac{df}{dx}=g(x,x)+\int _0^x \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}ds$

---

For more reference:

$\frac{d}{dx}\int _{\beta (x)}^{\alpha (x)}g(t)dt=\frac{d\alpha }{dx}g(\alpha (x))-\frac{d\beta }{dx}g(\beta (x))$

Comment: What if $g$ is not continuous?

Comment: This makes very little sense. Now the domain of $F$ is the product of $x$-space with the space of functions?

Comment: I just consider g to be another variable and try to do the same thing when dealing with z'(t) where z=z(x,y),x=x(t),y=y(t).